# (Recursion) How to get all key/value pairs from an Object with nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, recursion

I have an object that look like this:

```
        {
            "id": 45745049
            "seller": {
                "first_name": "Sam",
                "last_name": "Smith",
                "email": "samsmith@smith.com",
                "phone": {
                    "number": "1111-1111",
                    "verified": false
                },
            },
            "order_items": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "id": "29239765",
                        "title": "item1",
                        "colors": [
                             "red",
                             "green",
                             "blue"
                        ]
                    },
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "unit_price": 230,
                },
                {
                    "item": {
                        "id": "238457363",
                        "title": "item2",
                        "colors": [
                             "red"
                        ]
                    },
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "unit_price": 110,
                }
            ],
            "date_created": "2020-08-03T12:17:25.000-04:00",
            "date_last_updated": "2020-08-03T16:51:35.61Z"
        }
```

I want an array with pairs of EVERY key in the object with the value.

For example:

```
[
  ["id", 45745049], 
  ["first_name", "Sam"], 
  ....., 
  ["phone.number", "1111-1111"], 
  ["phone.verified", false], 
  ....etc
]
```

Everything Ok until that point. The problem is when a property is an array of objects. The output I want is the following:

```
[
   ..., 
   ["order_items1.item.id", 29239765], 
   ["order_items1.item.colors1", "red"], 
   ["order_items1.item.colors2", "green"], 
   ..., 
   ["order_items2.item.id", 238457363], 
   ["order_items2.item.colors1", "red"], 
   ...etc
]
```

So it needs to check if the property is an array and add the position number if so.

I know I need a recursive function but I dont know how to do it.
This is what I got until now.

```
getObjectKeys = (obj) => {
    let FieldName = "";
    let FieldValue = "";
    for(var prop in obj) {
        FieldName += prop;
        if(!(prop instanceof Array) && (typeof prop !== "object") && obj[prop]) {
            FieldValue = obj[prop];
        } else if(prop instanceof Array && prop.length !== 0){
            prop.forEach((innerItem, i) => {
                FieldName += `${i+1}.`;
                // check if the inner item is an array or whatever an do it all again
                // Dont know what to do here.                   
            });
        } else {
            getObjectKeys(obj[prop]);
        }        
    }
    return [FieldName, FieldValue];
    
}
```

Note: I dont want the empty or null keys.

I would be very grateful if someone can help me. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Are you sure you want `["order_items1.item.id", 29239765]`? This not a proper array because of the dot inside the key . If you e.g. make a console.log from this array this key/value pair is not presented. You can only get the value by address it by address it through `arr["order_items1.item.id"]`.

Comment: @Sascha Yeah, I know. But I dont want to access that key later. Only need the key as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does something very similar to what you're looking for.  It's a technique [I use often](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63075744).

```js
const getPaths = (obj) =>
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (([k, v]) => getPaths (v) .map (p => [k, ... p]))
    : [[]]

const path = (ps) => (obj) => 
  ps .reduce ((o, p) => (o || {}) [p], obj)

const flatten = (obj) => 
  Object .fromEntries (getPaths (obj) .map (p => [p.join('.'), path (p) (obj)]))

const input = {id: 45745049, seller: {first_name: "Sam", last_name: "Smith", email: "samsmith@smith.com", phone: {number: "1111-1111", verified: false}}, order_items: [{item: {id: "29239765", title: "item1", colors: ["red", "green", "blue"]}, quantity: 1, unit_price: 230}, {item: {id: "238457363", title: "item2", colors: ["red"]}, quantity: 2, unit_price: 110}], date_created: "2020-08-03T12: 17: 25.000-04: 00", date_last_updated: "2020-08-03T16: 51: 35.61Z"}

console .log (flatten (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The differences are that there is a separator before the array index and that I use zero-based arrays, not one-based arrays.

I would suggest that it's a much better output format.  If nothing else, it would probably allow you to rehydrate the original format.  But if you want to change it, you should probably simply `reduce` the path to combine the numeric elements with their predecessors, something like:

```js
const flatten = (obj) => 
  Object .fromEntries (getPaths (obj) .map (p => [
    p .reduce (
      (a, k) => /^\d+$/ .test(k) ? [...a .slice (0, -1), a [a .length - 1] + (1 + (+k))] : [...a, k], 
      []
    ) .join ('.'), 
    path2 (p) (obj)
  ]))
```

But this would require changes if the outer object might be an array.

Again, though, absent a very good reason to use your requested format, I would strongly recommend my alternative.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I dont understand the code completely and maybe I will need to make some tweaks but thats what I was looking for (kind of). I'm going to read it more carefully later because my head is going to explode now lol. Thank you again, you're a genius.